# Jinternalframe not working properly

Tags: java, swing, jinternalframe

Hi I have few Internalframes which has default min/max and restore buttons.It works fine when it is in default state but when you restore the main frame then it does not work properly.Suppose two Internal frames are in min state and one in max state.Now if you MAx the main container then all the min internal frames disappears>please find the code below.Please find the attached screenshot

```
package tryout;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.*;

public class Test3 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test3();
    }

    private int xpos = 0;
    private int ypos = 0;

    public Test3() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (Exception exp) {
                    exp.printStackTrace();
                }
                DesktopPane pane = new DesktopPane();
                pane.add(newInternalFrame());
                pane.add(newInternalFrame());
                pane.add(newInternalFrame());

                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.add(pane);
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setSize(400, 400);
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);

            }
        });
    }

    public JInternalFrame newInternalFrame() {
        JInternalFrame inf = new JInternalFrame("Blah", true, false, true, true);
        inf.setLocation(xpos, ypos);
        inf.setSize(100, 100);
        inf.setVisible(true);
inf.repaint();
inf.revalidate();
        xpos += 50;
        ypos += 50;

        return inf;
    }

    public class DesktopPane extends JDesktopPane {

        @Override
        public void doLayout() {
            super.doLayout();
            List<Component> icons = new ArrayList<Component>(25);
            int maxLayer = 0;

            for (Component comp : getComponents()) {
                if (comp instanceof JInternalFrame.JDesktopIcon) {
                    icons.add(comp);
                    maxLayer = Math.max(getLayer(comp), maxLayer);
                }
            }

            maxLayer++;
            int x = 0;
            for (Component icon : icons) {

                int y = getHeight() - icon.getHeight();
                icon.setLocation(x, y);
                x += icon.getWidth();
                setLayer(icon, maxLayer);

            }
        }
     /*   public void doLayout() {
            super.doLayout();
            List<Component> icons = new ArrayList<Component>(25);
            for (Component comp : getComponents()) {
                if (comp instanceof JInternalFrame.JDesktopIcon) {
                    icons.add(comp);
                }
            }

            int x = 0;
            for (Component icon : icons) {

                int y = getHeight() - icon.getHeight();
                icon.setLocation(x, y);
                x += icon.getWidth();

            }
        }*/
    }
}
```

Comment: Tried Mac and Windows 7, couldn't replicate the issue

Comment: I do see the problems you describe. The question is why are you trying do override the doLayout() code? It appears you are attempting to duplicate the default layout code. Get rid of the doLayout() method.

Comment: @camickr thanks for your reply. I have a requirement and hence i did this way.I have to create components and each havving three buttons min,max and restore. when i press the min buttons then it should come down and when i press the max buttons then that particular frame gets minimized showing the min frames at the bottom.So i did like this. If you have any other way to that then please let me know

Comment: @MadProgrammer Thanks for your reply.Please tell me how to get rid of this. you already know my requirements so please tell me is there any other way

Comment: @sukant I've run you code you 3 systems and can't replicate the problem you are describing. I even changed it to use the `DefaultDesktopManager` and still can't get it to do what you described.

Comment: @MadProgrammer  sorry but i did not get what you mean to say

Comment: @sukant I mean that I've run it two PC's running Windows 7 and one running Mac OS without been able to duplicate the problem you have described...until now...

Comment: @MadProgrammer you are a genius in java .If you can not solve it then think about it me

Comment: @sukant From the looks of things, it might be better to create your own `DesktopManager`

Comment: @MadProgrammer nice answer Please see the attached file

Comment: @MadProgrammer can you give me some suggestions for the above question?

Comment: @sukant First, that's a separate question, you really shouldn't modify the questions this way, unless you are trying to clarify the original. Second, I played around with the `DesktopManager`, but something keeps screwing up the bounds of the maximized window when the desktop is resized and I can't track down whoes doing it (I think it might be in the UI class somewhere).  But you should have enough information from the `doLayout` method to figure it out.

Comment: @MadProgrammer ok then i am rolling back

Comment: You're questions aren't bad, but they some times lack any effort on your part.  For instance, the latest question can be solved simply by modifying the `doLayout` method you already have.

Comment: @MadProgrammer Thanks for your reply,I am new to swing and started working on it since last 20 days. I think i will be a master in it if you help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is more of a hack then a solution.

Why it happens, I don't know, but for some reason when the desktop pane is resized, it appears that the maximized window is been brought to the front regardless of all the other components (and there layer properties)

This seems to have forced the desktop pane to honor the layer properties.

```
public class DesktopPane extends JDesktopPane {

    public DesktopPane() {
        addComponentListener(new ComponentAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e) {
                revalidate();
                repaint();
            }
        });
    }

    /*...*/

}
```